# networkX equivalent to igraph vertexClustering

Tags: python, igraph, networkx

python's igraph has a function clusters() that allows you to turn a Graph into a vertexClustering via

```
igraph.Graph().clusters(mode ='STRONG')
```

This allows me to take a graph and come up with a list of all nodes that are connected together. My question is, does networkX have an equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your question is about finding strongly connected components in directed graphs (because of the term `strong`).

You should look at [`strongly_connected_components`](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.strongly_connected.strongly_connected_components.html?highlight=strongly%20connected)

If you are just looking at undirected graphs, then [`connected_components`](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components.html?highlight=connected_components) should help.  This returns a generator of sets of nodes.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for! I ended up using   connected_components and making a list of it @Joel